# Why is the floating element not detached from the document flow when its container has no height?

Tags: html, css

```
<form style="background-color:pink; height:100px">
        <label for="button-test">Add your name here</label>
        <input type="text" id="button-test" name="button" placeholder="add your name here">
    <div style="display:inline-block; height:">
        <input class="button-image" type="image" src="submit.png" alt="image button" width="40" height="40">
    </div>
</form>
```

and CSS:

```
.button-image {

    margin-left:20px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:px;
    }
```

If i don't add height to the div container, and try to add margin-top to the child-element "button-image", all 3 elements move down. But if i add height to the div container of the button-image, now the margin-top only moves the button-image element, while the other 2 stay on place.

I made the "button-image" element floating on purpose in order to be able to move it down a little bit without moving the other 2. Since all 3 are inline-block elements, setting a margin-top on either one of them, would move all 3 down, because they need to maintain the doc flow. I thought making the button-image element floating will take it out of the doc flow and i will be able to move it freely without effecting the others. But i discovered that, if the div container does not have a height, all 3 elements again move down when i set a margin-top to the floating "button-image" element. Why is that? Isn't that element supposed to be floating, and therefore be out of the document flow, and therefore not effect the others? Why is setting a margin-top makes the other elements move with it? If i add just 1px height to the div container, now only the floating element moves.

Can somebody explain what difference does the height make in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [CSS 2.2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#root-height):

> 10.6.7 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots
>
> ... if the element has any floating descendants whose bottom margin edge is below the element's bottom content edge, then the height is increased to include those edges.

This is the same rule as makes `overflow:hidden` on a block box contain a float, similar to a clearfix.

All inline-block elements are block formatting context roots, and so this rule applies to them when you don't specify a height, because the default height is auto.

Then at the very end of [Section 10](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html), the spec says:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

In your example, the inline-block contains only the float so it has no in-flow line boxes and therefore its baseline is its bottom margin edge. It has zero bottom padding, border, and margin, so its baseline is also its bottom content edge.

Then your label and text input vertically align their baseline to that inline-block bottom content edge, so the lower the bottom of the float is, the lower those elements will be to keep them vertically aligned.

But if you specify a height to the inline-block, its bottom content edge won't be moved down to enclose the float - i.e. the float will *overflow* the inline-block. The label and text input still vertically align with the bottom of the content box of the inline-block, but that's only as tall as the height you have specified.

---

To avoid this happening, the usual technique applies of breaking the baseline vertical alignment between the inline elements, by for example, setting the inline-block to `vertical-align:top`

Comment: Can you please explain this with more simple terms? I am still learning HTML and this explanation is too difficult to properly comprehend. My understanding of how floating works is that, when you make a child-element float, it sort of detached itself from its parent element, and it's no longer part of the doc flow, and it no longer "touches" the parent element, and the parent element loses its height and width because it doesn't contain anything anymore, and therefore the parent element should therefore sort of not exist in terms of size and properties. 

But in my example,

Comment: In my example, the div container has a width, which is the first thing that confuses me, since i thought it should not have a width, since its content is floating. So why does it have a width? And second, from what i could understand, you are saying that, the container doesn't have a height and therefore its height is the height of its content, and that's why when you add margin to the content, the container moves with it, and that drags down the other elements too, but if the container has any height, then the floating content overflows its container, which stays on one place, since it

Comment: it now has a height, and that's why the other elements don't move, since they align with the container, which maintains doc flow. 

So, first of all, is my understanding of your explanation correct? And second, is my understanding of how the float property works correct? I thought that, when the content is floating, it doesn't "touch" the container, so how can the container's height be the height of the content?  And why does the container has a width? This is what confuses me, unless my understanding of how floating works is incorrect.

Comment: The first part of your understanding is correct. It's mostly the relationship between floats and their containers you're not getting right. In broad terms, inline-blocks contain their floats, whereas block elements mostly don't, but we can use CSS to make them do so if we want.

Comment: I just tested this, and you were right. Inline-blocks do maintain their properties even when their content is floating, while block-level elements don't. I had no idea this is how it works. Thank you.